# Declaring array within array shows error in php

Tags: php, arrays

It shows

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in line 1

```
$test=  array (( [0] => array ( ['href'] => 'admin/manageusers', ['title'] => 'Setting', ['icon'] => 'icon-user', ['sub_menu'] => array ( [0] => array ( ['href'] => 'admin/manageusers/hoteladmins/edit-hoteladmin/29', ['title'] => 'Profile' ), [1] => array ( ['href'] => 'admin/manageusers/employee', ['title'] =>'Users' ), [2] => array ( ['href'] => 'admin/manageusers/pointssetting', ['title'] => 'Points' ), [3] => array ( ['href'] => 'admin/manageusers/transaction', ['title'] => 'Transaction' ) ) ) ) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In declaring you should not use `[0]` as a key, just `0`, so:

```
$test = array(
    0 => array(
        ['href']     => 'admin/manageusers',
        ['title']    => 'Setting',
        ['icon']     => 'icon-user',
        ['sub_menu'] => array(
            0 => array(
                ['href']  => 'admin/manageusers/hoteladmins/edit-hoteladmin/29',
                ['title'] => 'Profile'
            ),
            1 => array(
                ['href']  => 'admin/manageusers/employee',
                ['title'] => 'Users'
            ),
            2 => array(
                ['href']  => 'admin/manageusers/pointssetting',
                ['title'] => 'Points'
            ),
            3 => array(
                ['href']  => 'admin/manageusers/transaction',
                ['title'] => 'Transaction'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Also if you want to set increasing keys, you can skip those keys:

```
$test = array(
    array(
        ['href']     => 'admin/manageusers',
        ['title']    => 'Setting',
        ['icon']     => 'icon-user',
        ['sub_menu'] => array(
            array(
                ['href']  => 'admin/manageusers/hoteladmins/edit-hoteladmin/29',
                ['title'] => 'Profile'
            ),
            array(
                ['href']  => 'admin/manageusers/employee',
                ['title'] => 'Users'
            ),
            array(
                ['href']  => 'admin/manageusers/pointssetting',
                ['title'] => 'Points'
            ),
            array(
                ['href']  => 'admin/manageusers/transaction',
                ['title'] => 'Transaction'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: This will produce numerous "Illegal offset type" warnings.

Comment: @faintsignal Really ? Why ?

Comment: Well what did you tell the OP to do fix with his initial array key? Same principle applies to subarrays.

Comment: @faintsignal Look at my answer again and check if it's incorrect because I do not see any mistakes.

Comment: The `[]` need to removed from **all** keys. Run the code.

Comment: To be fair, on older versions of PHP you won't get any "illegal offset" warnings -- just a single parse error.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use **SQUARE** ([ ] ) brackets to define the new element and it will be OK.

Just look at the correct version:

```
$test = array(
    0 => array(
        'href' => 'admin/manageusers',
        'title' => 'Setting',
        'icon' => 'icon-user',
        'sub_menu' => array(
            0 => array(
                'href' => 'admin/manageusers/hoteladmins/edit-hoteladmin/29',
                'title' => 'Profile'
            ),
            1 => array('href' => 'admin/manageusers/employee', 'title' => 'Users'),
            2 => array('href' => 'admin/manageusers/pointssetting', 'title' => 'Points'),
            3 => array('href' => 'admin/manageusers/transaction', 'title' => 'Transaction')
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: `[ ]` are not "curly brackets".

Comment: Doh! what the hell is going on with me today, wow. Thank you @faintsignal !

Comment: No worries, it's just that we don't want to confuse the novices.

Answer (score 0):

```
$test = array(
array(
    'href' => 'admin/manageusers',
    'title' => 'Setting',
    'icon' => 'icon-user',
    'sub_menu' => array(
        array(
            'href' => 'admin/manageusers/hoteladmins/edit-hoteladmin/29',
            'title' => 'Profile'
        ),
        array('href' => 'admin/manageusers/employee', 'title' => 'Users'),
        array('href' => 'admin/manageusers/pointssetting', 'title' => 'Points'),
        array('href' => 'admin/manageusers/transaction', 'title' => 'Transaction')
    )
  )
);
```

Remove all `"["` and `"]"` as above